# Doubt in Proposition 2.2 chapter 3Neukirch algebraic number theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

[Prop2.2chapter3Neukirch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PMqK.png)

In this Proposition 2.2 of Chapter 3 of Neukirch Algebraic Number Theory I can't understand if $\mathcal{O_\mathfrak P}$ is the completion of $\mathcal{O}$ with respect to the ideal $\mathfrak P$ or the analytic completion with respect to the $\mathfrak P$-adic  absolute value.
Moreover in the proof of $(iii)$ I can't understand where it's used the fact that we can assume that $\mathcal{o}$ is a DVR.

Comment: The two types of completions you ask about *mean the same thing*.  What do you think the difference is between completing $\mathbf Q$ with respect to a prime $p$ and the "analytic completion" with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value?